# Как с помощью java script сделать автоматическое нажатие кнопки b1 на сайте, после того как загрузится картинка img1?

Tags: javascript

Имеется допустим сайт example.ru, на странице сайта есть картинка img1 и кнопка b1. Как сделать так, что-бы кнопка нажималась автоматически, после загрузки страницы и появления картинки img1?

Answer (score 0):

```js
image.onload = function(){
    someButton.click();
}
```